# set the height of the modal to be the same as the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on the image, the modal appears, I would like to make it the same height of the viewport and the same width of it, since as it looks like now I have to scroll down.

This is the css of the modal and the modal content:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

I've created a minimal example here

https://jsfiddle.net/rnyjdp87/1/

Also, I would like to put a button a button on the top right of each image that is gonna open a second modal if clicked (still have to do the second modal). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand but try this:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: none;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.modal-content img {
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will set your modal to 100% viewport height, 100% viewport width and changing overflow to none stops the scroll.

Comment: This kinda helped, but I still have to scroll down to see the whole image, I would like to have the whole picture displayed without having to scroll. Can I also remove thee site scrolling while the modal is displayed? Thank you for your fast reply btw!

Comment: I've updated my answer to add styles to the image itself, max-height of 80% of the viewport so it doesn't go off the bottom of the modal, and remove the 100% width by replacing with auto but set a max-width of 100% of the modal.

Comment: Impressive, it worked! Thank you! 
May I ask you the last question? Is there a way also to center the image and keep the next and prev buttons on the side? I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3ms70d9/.

I've tried with margin-right:auto and margin.left-auto.

Comment: margin-left and right: auto would only work on block elements, add `display: block` to your `.modal-content img` and that should do it.

Comment: Nice thank you! Just for info, in order to work with `display:block` I had to add also `margin:auto`.